# Get the DueDate if the date is today

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am assigned to create an alert that if today is the duedate of an item, then the alert will be sent to the team.

I am trying to check how I can filter the where clause of my code:

```
SELECT     dbo.salesorder.customerid, 
           dbo.salesorder.entrydate, 
           dbo.salesorder.salesorderno, 
           dbo.salesorderdetails.itemno, 
           dbo.salesorder.usercreated, 
           dbo.salesorder.duedate
from       dbo.salesorder 
inner JOIN dbo.salesorderdetails 
ON         dbo.salesorder.salesorderid = dbo.salesorderdetails.salesorderid
where     (dbo.salesorder.customerid = 238)
```

[image: See image below]

If today is 4th of May, I just my report to display the below-highlighted sales orders.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982870/sql-custom-alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert getdate() to date and compare with the duedate

```
where     (dbo.salesorder.customerid = 238)
and       dbo.salesorder.duedate = convert(date, getdate())
```

Comment: thank you @squirrel! just to confirm, if there's no order which is due today, meaning the alert won't run? right?

Comment: yes. There will not be any result return if there isn't any matching rows

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT     dbo.salesorder.customerid, 
           dbo.salesorder.entrydate, 
           dbo.salesorder.salesorderno, 
           dbo.salesorderdetails.itemno, 
           dbo.salesorder.usercreated, 
           dbo.salesorder.duedate
from       dbo.salesorder 
inner JOIN dbo.salesorderdetails 
ON         dbo.salesorder.salesorderid = dbo.salesorderdetails.salesorderid
where      dbo.salesorder.duedate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) --or CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) 
           and dbo.salesorder.customerid = 238
```

Comment: thank you @DT! just to confirm, if there's no order which is due today, meaning the alert won't run? right?

Comment: I believe so. But I cannot confirm it. This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27236412/6327676